# Groovy extension/Plugin with JDeveloper 11g

Tags: groovy, junit, spock, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I'm using JDeveloper 11g as my IDE and specifically v11.1.1.7.0. For reasons beyond the scope of this thread, I'm unable to upgrade JDeveloper to a newer version.

Im trying to use the Spock framework in order to write groovy-based unit tests. Is there a way to enable groovy support in my version of Jdev? I would need to be able to create groovy-based files and have the IDE recognize them.

Comment: Not really an answer, thus only a comment, but I'd recomment you switch to IntelliJ IDEA. It is the best Java IDE available and it has very good support for Spock tests, also knowing about its special syntax.

Comment: Oh definitely, but switching is not an option now.